# PDF inbound in text - cropping unwanted content

Tags: pdf, text, white-space

For this issue, I have no MWE.

**Problem:**

I have a word-file (survey, pretty complex structure) and I have been requested to use/integrate parts of this document for illustration in my LaTeX-file (e.g. a certain part of this survey). It is expected to have some illustrating text and adding the partial section of survey after this.

**Solution tried so far:**

1) When I use snipping tools to get a PNG-file and inbound this file in my document, the resulting quality is pretty weak compared to normal LaTeX output.

2) Thus, I considered deleting all parts from word-file - apart from relevant passage - and create a PDF-file from this. Then, I attempted to inbound this PDF-file. However, doing so, LaTeX inbounds whole PDF page, therefore there remains pretty much unwanted whitespace in PDF (actual passage is e.g. 1/4 page, rest whitespace).

**Question:**

How can I achieve inbound of PDF in text without unwanted whitespace (e.g. 1/4 page of it)? Any ideas?

Comment: in word zoom in as close as possible at largest resolution before starting/useing  print screen or snipping tool to grab an image of the highest resolution, if word encoded the image reduced at say 25% then a right click on the image **in word or pdf** may allow save as at source resolution (if your really lucky) if you have a way to zoom in even if clip area is off screen windows/acrobat/word will usually bump the pixels to match the broader virtual area (within reason) anyways save as png is probably the best for import graphics. The pdf route is more useful for vectors

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Any recommendation for a snipping tool which uses best resolution? Windows snipping tool is slightly disappointing to me.

Comment: All snipping is equal it is what controls the zoom that counts your avatar is a good symetrical example it is 32 bits x 32bits at 96 dpi that saves with a right click as 898 bytes it is very crisp. If I zoom my firefox browser to 200% your icon is now 64x64 and if I snip it as png it becomes 3618 bytes (about 4 times much as expected) but is is now not as crisp since windows has interpolated the alias values between each pixel so In this case zoom and snip efectively make things worse e.g. not as crisp as the smaller right click download of the source png, Those are needed to get best results.